# Como inserir dados de um array, dentro de outro para tipo objeto

Tags: javascript

Tenho o array da seguinte forma:

```
let arrTeste = [ [ '1', '10' ], [ '2', '30' ], [ '3', '40' ] ]
```

Como seria para pegar os dados dos sub array e transforma para algo tipo:

```
let Obj={ 
          { item:'1', quantidade:'10'}, 
          { item:'2', quantidade:'30'}, 
          { item:'3', quantidade:'40'} 
}
```

ou

```
let obj=[ 
          { item:'1', quantidade:'10'}, 
          { item:'2', quantidade:'30'}, 
          { item:'3', quantidade:'40'} 
]
```

Comment: O que tentou até o momento e quais erros que deu o seu algoritmo. Coloque um [MCVE] apresentando sua tentativa em abordar o problema.

Comment: Caro boa tarde, obrigado por tentar ajudar, porem essa parte era a única duvida que estava tendo... o que o colega postou em seguida, esclareceu.

Comment: obrigado Augusto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode mapear para uma nova variável os dados contidos em um `array` e pegando cada posição e transformando em objetos com chave e valor e para isso utilize o  método [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) do `array` para recriar esse `array` de objetos, ***exemplo***:

```js
const arrTeste = [
  ['1', '10'],
  ['2', '30'],
  ['3', '40']
];

const obj = arrTeste.map((item) => {
  return {'item': item[0], 'quantidade': item[1]}
});

console.log(obj);
```

a outra forma que é um objeto e dentro desse objeto vários outros objetos não é correto, pois não tem a chave e também não vai retornar um `array` de informação.

Comment: Obrigado pelo tempo em responder, foi muito util

Comment: Se for útil assinale como resposta da sua pergunta.